# Bison & flex linkage - yylval type

Tags: bison, flex-lexer, lex

I have a school project, building a compiler. There is a header file given by the course staff, "proj.h" including a struct "Node", which should be used to build the parsing tree, and a set of functions.
(That header does not include a `#define` for `YYSTYPE` to the Node type, and shouldn't be changed).
I would like to use `Node*` in my .lex file, such as:

```
yylval = makeNode(...);
```

definition of makeNode:

```
Node *makeNode(const char* type,const char* value, Node *child);
```

I have tried defining the YYSTYPE both in .lex file and .ypp.

.lex:

```
#include "proj.h"
#include "parser.tab.hpp"
#define YYSTYPE Node*
```

.ypp:

```
#include "proj.h"
#define YYSTYPE Node*
```

I'm compiling using g++.
It seems that the lval doesn't get the actual defintion as Node* as it should. There is a compilation error when trying to assign lval:

```
Invalid conversion from 'Node* {aka n*}' to 'YYSTYPE {aka int}'
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: That sounds like you don't `#define YYSTYPE` early enough. Could you be a bit clearer where the lines you quote appear in the files? Did you use `-Wall` in your g++ command? What other errors/warnings were produced? (I'd definitely put the define before including the bison header file.)

Comment: I have tried that too, defining YYSTYPE before including the .tab.cpp.
When doing so, it seems that the tab.cpp file does not include the proj header, since I get "undifined reference to 'makeNode'".
the compilation command is:
`g++ parser.tab.cpp lex.yy.c`

Comment: And where is makeNode *defined*? That error doesn't say it is undeclared, so there is no evidence that the header file is being skipped (which could not happen without an error message, anyway.)

Comment: Actually, it was a linkage error, compiling proj.c as well solved the problem. Thanks!